# Convolution of a wavfile on Matlab

Tags: matlab, echo, convolution

I'm doing an assignment to generate echo on Matlab using convolution 
I don't understand what `wavread` actually does. Is the output a vector that I can use in a convolution?

I tried so and got an error " A and B must be vectors."

Another question: If the signal that I get from the wave file is `x(t)`, how can I get `x(t-4)`?

Comment: you need to provide more info on what you're trying to do. It is entirely possible that the second signal that you're convolving with is not a vector. Or you could be reading in multi-channel data.

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in my comment, you're most probably trying to read in a multi-channel audio file, in which case `wavread` might most probably return an `NxM` array, where `N` is the number of samples and `M` is the number of channels. Could you post the output of `size(x)`, where `x` is the output of `wavread`?

Depending on what you want to do, you can either average across the channels to get a single audio vector (like a mono) as `xAvg=mean(x,2);`, or you can choose a specific channel to work with like `xChannelK=x(:,k);`, where `1<=k<=M` is the chosen channel.

In response to your comment above on zero padding, remember that in a convolution operation between an `n` point and an `m` point signal, you end up with an `m+n-1` point output. Say you want to convolve `A=[a1,a2,a3]` and `B=[b1,b2,b3]`. You first flip one of the vectors around, and slide it across the other, while multiplying point-wise and adding the result at each step.

However, when you flip it around, the second vector sticks out in sequence space at points where the other function is not defined (and vice versa). So you need to pad them with zeros till they're both the same length.

This is better shown by an example. The first point in the output is

```
0   0    a1   a2  a3
b3  b2   b1    0   0
--------------------
0 + 0 + a1b1 + 0 + 0  
--------------------

 = a1b1
```

Here we have padded `A` and `B` with zeros at points where the other is not defined. The second point in the output is

```
0    a1     a2    a3  0
b3   b2     b1    0   0
-----------------------
0 + a1b2 + a2b1 + 0 + 0
-----------------------

 = a1b2+a2b1
```

and so on. You should go through the [wiki article on convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) for more info. However, you needn't do this by hand. MATLAB's [`conv`](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/conv.html) will automatically do this for you. So all you need to do is get your vectors in order and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, wavread produces a vector for its output (use Matlab help or type 'docsearch wavread' from the command window).  You can also double-check using the isvector(x) function.

Matlab vectors use indexing in order to identify the location within the vector, here, your signal x.  If you used wavread in this way:

```
x = wavread(*filename*)
```

then x can be called on as x, or x(:), or x(1:end).  This is important if you want to reference x(t-4).  If x(t) can be represented as x(1:end), then what should x(t-4) be?

The trick, however, is that an index can never be a negative value, so you cannot just say x(t-4) is x(-3:end-4).  With convolution, you may have to use some zero-padding, if it isn't already done in your convolution function.

I hope this helps, and good luck!

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by zero padding by a quick example?               also isvector(x) gives a zero so it's not a vector

Comment: If isvector(x) is false, then you are likely not using wavread properly or the file you are looking at is not a .wav file.  Look at the documentation for wavread.